# Powershell - Get file size by similar name

Tags: powershell

When I run "`Get-ChildItem`" PowerShell returns below

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 abc.123.Copy.2.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 abc.123.Copy.3.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 abc.123.Copy.4.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 abc.123.Copy.6.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 zxc.098.Copy.2.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 zxc.098.Copy.3.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 zxc.098.Copy.4.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 zxc.098.Copy.5.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47726 zxc.098.Copy.6.pdf
-a----        2021-05-02   9:45 PM          47756 poi.787.Copy.1.pdf
```

How can I find out how to get the amount of files and their total sizes based on the similar starting name to output something like below?

```
Total size of similar files:
abc = 190,904
zxc = 238,630
poi = 47756 


Total files:
abc = 4
zxc = 5
poi = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to group the files by the first token of the split string and they all follow this naming convention, you can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group them and then loop over them to get the desired output. I would advise you to output an object instead of a string since an object can be [exported to CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) and be easily sorted / filtered.

The code to run would be similar to this:

```sh
Get-ChildItem /path/to/files -File | Group-Object { $_.Name.Split('.')[0] } | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Count        = $_.Count
        StartingName = $_.Name
        TotalLength  = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([int64[]]$_.Group.Length)
    }
}
```

As for testing how the output would look, based on your sample data:

```
Count StartingName TotalLength
----- ------------ -----------
    4 abc               190904
    5 zxc               238630
    1 poi                47756
```